# Calling specific descendant of interface in an implementation of another interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract

I have an interface `iClass` defined. One method in the interface takes another interface, `iObject`, as an argument.

In one specific implementation of `iClass`, I need the method to take a specific implementation of `iObject`, `ObjectImplementation` - but C# tells me I need to implement the method as is.

Why is this? isn't `ObjectImplementation` an instance of `iObject`? How do I get around this? I tried using an abstract class instead and I get into the same mess.

```
public interface iClass {
    bool SomeMethod(iObject object);
}

public interface iObject {
    ... // some methods here
}

public ObjectImplementation : iObject {
    ... // some method implementations here
}

public ClassImplementation : iClass {
    public bool SomeMethod(ObjectImplementation object) // <- C# compiler yells at me
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The contract clearly states that the method requires an `iObject`. `ObjectImplementation` is *one* class implementing this interface. But there might be others. The contract of `iClass` states that *all* those implementations are valid parameters.

If you really need to constrain the parameter to `ObjectImplementation` consider using a generic interface:

```
public interface IClass<T> where T : IObject
{
    bool SomeMethod(T item);
}

public ClassImplementation : IClass<ObjectImplementation>
{
    public bool SomeMethod(ObjectImplementation item)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the iObject as parameter is a way to go, this should also work:

```
public interface iClass {
    bool SomeMethod(iObject obj);
}

public interface iObject {
}

public class ObjectImplementation : iObject {
}

public class ClassImplementation : iClass {
    public bool SomeMethod(iObject obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the implementation of `SomeMethod` in `ClassImplementation` really needs an `ObjectImplementation` and nothing else. E.g. because `ObjectImplementation` has additional members.